# Draw Shadow Only *Around* UIView Which Contains Transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, shadow

Question I'm struggling on. I've searched SO for a fair good time by now, but couldn't find an answer.

I have a `UIView` which contains alpha value of `0.5`, means - it `transparent`.

If I'm applying the usual code for `UIView` shadowing -

```
 class func applyShadow(view : UIView)
    {
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.15).CGColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0.5)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 1.3
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        view.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    }
```

The "fill" of the my `UIView` get shadowed as well.

**How can I draw the shadow only on the "border" path of my `UIView`, excluding the `UIView` fill?**

Comment: What's the full colour of your view and size of your view.

Comment: @Joe let's say : frame : (30,30,100,50). BackgroundColor : UiColor.redColor(colorWithAlpha : 0.5)

Comment: from your code. your shadow values are very small not visible enough. i believe you trying to make a drop shadow on your view ?. try adding small hairline border to your view with lightColor.it should works.

Comment: @Joe  Hey! The values are just for this sample. When there is transparency, the Shadow is drawing within the UIView container. I need the same effect, just draw the UIView only to the "border", not including the rest of the UIView

Comment: this is now possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884

Answer (score 0):

For 2022 this is now possible.

Essentially you do this:

```
shadowHole.fillRule = .evenOdd
shadowHole.path = p.cgPath
```

full details ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884